# How to create a dynamic nested dictionary data structure in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Building on top of the inbuilt python dict class, create a dynamic dictionary data structure (CustomDict) which can repeatedly add nested dictionaries on update, and can query a nested key without creating false data or raising an error.

This is how the data structure should behave:

```
# adding an dict in the nest
>>> nums = CustomDict()
>>> nums['one']['two']['three']['four'] = 4
>>> nums
{'one': {'two': {'three': {'four': 4}}}}

# querying a key
>>> nums['odd']['three']['five']  # does not raise KeyError
None
```

Subclasssing `collections.defaultdict` works but it creates false data in the dict.

Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def nested_dict():
    return defaultdict(nested_dict)

>>> d = nested_dict()
>>> d['x']['y']['z']
>>> d
defaultdict(<function nested_dict at 0x7fa79cef3310>, {'x': defaultdict(<function nested_dict at 0x7fa79cef3310>, {'y': defaultdict(<function nested_dict at 0x7fa79cef3310>, {'z': defaultdict(<function nested_dict at 0x7fa79cef3310>, {})})})})
```

Question was deferred from [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Define false data.

Comment: @Torxed I think simic0de does not want values inserted on lookup.